# Handling Sub-Components with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to rebuild [this](http://imgur.com/a/O1kGT) using React.

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
[
        {
            title: "Google",
            url: "www.google.com"
            tab: "Tab A",
            section: "Section A"
        },
        {
            title: "Facebook",
            url: "www.facebook.com"
            tab: "Tab B",
            section: "Section A"
        },
        {
            title: "Yahoo",
            url: "www.yahoo.com"
            tab: "Tab B",
            section: "Section B"
        },
        {
            title: "Reddit",
            url: "www.reddit.com"
            tab: "Tab C",
            section: "Section A"
        }
    ]
```

I've gotten this far where I'm able to create the tabs by calling a Tab component in my HomeNav component:

```
    class Tabs extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { items: [], index: null }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Keep the scope of this function so it can be used in checkFlag
    this.setState({
      items: this.props.items,
      index: this.props.index
    })
  }

  render() {
    var {item, index} = this.props
    return (
      <details key={item} id={"details-panel" + (++index)}>
        <summary>{item}</summary>
        <p>{"Something something" + item}</p>
      </details>
    )
  }
};

class HomeNav extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { items: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Keep the scope of this function so it can be used in checkFlag
    this.setState({
      items: data
    })
  }

  render() {
    let uniqueTabs = _.uniq(_.map(data, x => x.tab)).sort()

    let tabs = uniqueTabs.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Tabs key={item} item={item} index={index} />
      )
    })

    return (
      <section>
        <h3>Home Nav</h3>
        <div className="wb-tabs">
          <div className="tabpanels">
            {tabs}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
};
```

From what I understand I probably need sub-components for each section and another component for each link? So I broke down the html like this:

```
<!-- Main Component -->
<section>
  <div class="wb-tabs">
    <div class="tabpanels">
      {{TAB}}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- {{TAB} -->}
<details id="details-panel1">
  <summary>{{item.tab}}</summary>
  {{SECTION}}
</details>

<!-- {{SECTION}} -->
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h2 class=" bg-corp-med  h5">What’s new?</h2>
  <ul>
    {{LINKS}}
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- {{LINKS}} -->
<li>
  <a href="{{item.url}}">
    <strong>
      <span class="small">{{item.title}}</span>
    </strong>
  </a>
</li>
```

I'm also not sure how I'm suppose to place each object in their corresponding tab and section. Any help would be great

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fc3naL7/2/)